# Exception in SharePoint 2010 Web Service and Other Problems

Tags: 2010, installation, windows-7

everyone!

I'm having problems with my SharePoint 2010 installation. I have SP1 + the August 2012 CU and I am running on Windows 7. It's a fresh installation, although I had SP installed previously on my machine, all of the databases and 14 hive files were deleted prior to the new installation.

The problem is the infamous

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
```

I was having problems managing all of my service applications (user profile, managed metadata, bcs), and enabled the inclusion of exceptions for the WCF web services. When I directly access http://:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc, here's the exception I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement
Error: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface. ----> System.InvalidOperationException: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement.System.ServiceModel.Description.IPolicyExportExtension.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

The application pool SharePoint Web Services Root is running as a domain account which is a local administrator. It has access to all of the SP databases.

When I try to manage one of my service applications, for example, bcs, I get this on ULS:

```
WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://<host>:32843/35a0bc1b97c14b1698ca561f63631ce8/ProfilePropertyService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService' Action: 'http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetProfileProperties' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:ac76a7a3-b15b-405b-9c65-1e83f67baddd'

Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:     
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:     
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()
...
```

I understand lots of people are complaining about this, but haven't been able to find a solution, and tried most of those described on the Internet.

My current user, as well as the user running the service application pool, are set as administrators for all of the service applications and are also farm administrators.

Also, all services are running, except User Profile Synchronization, which I don't need.

Everything on Central Administration seems to work fine, and I can even manage the Secure Store.

Also, I can't login as the farm administrator, which is the farm account! Normally, when I access Central Administration, it logs me in automatically (as System Account); if I try to login as a different user, and specify it properly (domain\account), it just keeps presenting the login dialog box!

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out. I needed to reinstall SharePoint as stand-alone on my development machine. More information here: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2012/09/19/fixing-sharepoint-2010-permission-problems-on-windows-7.aspx

Comment: Well, because it was my own... but not it is.